# Spring batch, where/how to save the metadata about jobs

Tags: spring, spring-batch

How do I set any external database (mysql, postgres I'm not concerned with which one at this point) for usage with metadata?

At the moment I have spring batch writing the results of jobs to Mongodb and that works fine but I'm not keeping track of job status so the jobs are being run from the start every time even if interrupted halfway though.

There are plenty examples of how to avoid doing this, but can't seem to find a clear answer on what I need to configure to send the metadata somewhere real rather than in-memory.

I attempted adding a properties file but that had no effect

```
#    for Postgres:
batch.jdbc.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
batch.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/postgres
batch.jdbc.user=postgres
batch.jdbc.password=mysecretpassword
batch.database.incrementer.class=org.springframework.jdbc.support.incrementer.PostgreSQLSequenceMaxValueIncrementer
batch.schema.script=classpath:/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-postgresql.sql
batch.drop.script=classpath:/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-drop-postgresql.sql
batch.jdbc.testWhileIdle=false
batch.jdbc.validationQuery=
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There are plenty examples of how to avoid doing this, but can't seem to find a clear answer on what I need to configure to send the metadata somewhere real rather than in-memory.

You need to configure a bean of type `DataSource` in your batch application context (or extend the `DefaultBatchConfigurer` and set the data source you want to use to store meta-data).

There are many samples here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/tree/master/spring-batch-samples

You can find the data source configuration here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-samples/src/main/resources/data-source-context.xml